# PhantomJS not working when process started in WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, phantomjs

I have a C# method which starts phantomJS.exe process (passes the path to a JS file and a url) to fetch html for that url. That works all fine when called from a web api action method cranked up within Owin.

Now I have created a separate ASP.NET WebApp (empty project, uses IIS express) and have added a HttpModule to it. The call from HttpModule returns null data. Any idea why this would be the case? I have confirmed that the class can make outgoing http calls from that method.

From cmd, I have navigated to the bin folder for this project and ran phantomjs with these parameters and successfully got the result.

Any thoughts?

HttpModule (Caller):

```
private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;

    context.Response.ClearContent();

    var service = new GetRenderedHtmlForUrlService();
    var result = service.GetHtml("http://www.example.com/");
    context.Response.Write(result);
}
```

PhantomJS Runner:

```
public string GetHtml(string url)
{
    var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "Seo\\echo-html.js " + url;
    processStartInfo.FileName = @"phantomjs.exe";

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
    (
        delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.Data is always null when called from my webapp
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data)) return;

            outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
        }
    );

    var started = process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    process.CancelOutputRead();
    process.Kill();
    return outputBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE:** more info that might help: there are no exceptions. I have checked process.StandardError and it's empty. PhantomJS is in PATH and using it this way works from command line.

Comment: -1: There are couple questions related to running processes from ASP.Net and PhantomJS in particular on this site already. Please check related questions and add more information to your post: exceptions you see, output of process, current working directory and absolute path to PhantomJS, permissions...

Comment: Alexei, I have looked at other related questions first and they did not help. I've added a bit of more info, hope they help. Maybe read through the question and if you are willing to assist, ask for clarifications before quickly downvoting.

Comment: Better (removed downvote). Check Error output too - `BeginErrorReadLine`/`ErrorDataReceived`

Comment: where do you return something in GetHtml ?

Comment: Oops! Had missed the return line. Now added.